# sublime text 3 hints as in NetBeans

Tags: php, autocomplete, sublimetext3, hints

is there any extension that provide hints (autocomplete) in Sublime Text 3 as it in NetBeans?
Not just php functions but all object methods, attributes and so on. Basicly it is usefull when you use OOP, frameworks etc.

[image: NetBeans X SublimeText hints]

Comment: No it's not currently possible. Keep in mind NetBeans is an IDE and ST is a text editor. The IDE has knowledge about the structure and dependencies of your project. Tool tips have been requested for ST, but they aren't yet implemented.

Answer (score 5):

You should take a look at [SublimeCodeIntel](https://github.com/SublimeCodeIntel/SublimeCodeIntel). Quite nice, and works not only with PHP.

You can install it via [Package Control](https://sublime.wbond.net/). The GitHub repository of the project also tells you how to install, if not using Package Control. (I happened to have bugs with the package control version, so I also installed without package control, but first try that, my friends didn't have my issue.)

Keep in mind, that Sublime does not have an API that would make possible the same user experience. With this extension you'll get lists like the autocomplete. These lists can also contain PHPDoc, but not in a separate tooltip window, like in Netbeans. IMHO it still is very-very useful, and it might satisfy you.

Answer (score 2):

you can use "Intelli​Docs" plugin

https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/IntelliDocs

press F2 key on the function

but not working in the popup

Answer (score 1):

ya you can install **AndyPhp** package in **sublime text 3**.